# Join two queries together

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a database that holds a bunch of student information in the following tables

```
Student:
    id
    created_on
    updated_on

StudentHistory
    id
    studentid
    schoolid
    gradeid
    datestamp
    active
```

The student history manages how students change over the years and allows me to report back student growth.

I now need to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM students
INNER JOIN studenthistory
    ON student.id = studenthistory.studentid
WHERE studenthistory.active = 1
```

The problem is that the query won't necessarilly pull the latest history record like I need.  Is there a way that I can guarentee that only the latest history record will get pulled in the join?

Comment: how about adding "order by datestamp desc" and get the first row

Comment: That's not enough, he probably wants the most recent history for each student

Comment: I did want the most recent history for each student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students s
JOIN    studentshistory sh
ON      sh.id =
        (
        SELECT  shi.id
        FROM    studentshistory shi
        WHERE   shi.studentid = s.id
                AND shi.active = 1
        ORDER BY
                studentid DESC, active DESC, datestamp DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `studentshistory (studentid, active, datestamp, id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: You dont need to sort on studentid, or active or id.

Comment: @Frits: sorting on `studentid, active` will make `MySQL` to use the index correctly. Sorting on `id` will get rid of the duplicates. Was it the reason of your downvote?

Comment: What index? You don't need an index. Don't over-complicate matters.

Comment: @Frits: are you sure you know what an index is and what's its purpose?

Comment: Indexes are strictly for performance and this looks like a really large index for a fairly frivolous task. I don't think it's worth the speed gain, but you'd have to test this. I'm also not convinced this query actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Frits: do I understand you right: you are giving a downvote for an advice to improve performance?

Comment: I'll take away the downvote but I'm not at all convinced this query works. Ah .. I can't, you have to edit it first .. silly StackOverflow.

Comment: @Frits: just to clarify: this is not a forum, this is a Q&A site. Usually, the best method to convince is to write your own answer.

Comment: @Frits, this answer does actually work, and because of the amount of data I am querying against, I did have to make the indexes to get any real performance gain.

Comment: +1 for interesting use of `JOIN.. ON` syntax. Would be particularly interesting when used with a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Conrad: what's so interesting about it? :)

Comment: @Quassnoi I've never seen the Sub query on right side of the `=` on a `JOIN` expression

Comment: @Conrad: ah, then feel free to look at at :) With a `LEFT JOIN` it will return students with no active history records as well.

Comment: @Quassnoi. Oh I see why would a `LEFT JOIN` be particularly interesting. With an `INNER JOIN` this could also be solved less "exotically" with an IN or EXISTS. But if it required a `LEFT JOIN\IN` solution I would need to add (`OR field IS NULL`) or use a derived table\inline view. This way one doesn't require the `OR ISNULL` or an extra derived table\inline view when using a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Students
INNER JOIN StudentHistory sh1 
  ON Student.studentid = sh1.studentid 
  AND StudentHistory.datestamp = 
    (SELECT MAX(datestamp) 
     FROM StudentHistory sh2 
     WHERE sh2.studentid = sh1.studentid);
```